# Laravel liebig/cron executes the cronjob twice for same time

Tags: laravel, cron

I am using `laravel 4.2`.

I've a project requirement to send some analysis report email to all the users every `Monday 6 am`.

Obviously its a scheduled task, hence I've decided to use `cron-job`.

For this I've installed `liebig/cron` package. The package is installed successfully. To test email, I've added following code in `app/start/global.php`:

```
Event::listen('cron.collectJobs', function() {
    Cron::setEnablePreventOverlapping();

    // to test the email, I am setting the day of week to today i.e. Tuesday
    Cron::add('send analytical data', '* * * * 2', function() {

        $maildata = array('email' => 'somedomain@some.com');

        Mail::send('emails.analytics', $maildata, function($message){
            $message->to('some_email@gmail.com', 'name of user')->subject('somedomain.com analytic report');
        });

        return null;

    }, true);

    Cron::run();
});
```

Also in `app\config\packages\liebig\cron\config.php` the key `preventOverlapping` is set to `true`.

Now, if I run it like `php artisan cron:run`, **it sends the same email twice** with the same time.

I've deployed the same code on my **DigitalOcean development server (ubuntu)** and set its `crontab` to execute this command `every minute` but still it is sending the same email twice.

Also it is not generating `lock file` in `app/storage` directory, according to some search results I've come to know that it creates a `lock file` to prevent overlapping. the directory has full permissions granted.

Can anybody knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Remove `Cron::run()`.

Here's what's happening:

- Your Cron route or cron:run command is invoked.
- Cron fires off the `cron.collectjobs` event to get a list of events.
- You call `Cron::run()` and run all the events.
- Cron calls `Cron::run()` and runs all the events.

In the `cron.collectjobs` event you should only be making a list of jobs using `Cron::add()`.

---

The reason you're not seeing a lock file is either that `preventOverlapping` is set to `false` (it's `true` by default), or that the jobs are running so fast you don't see it being created and deleted. The lock file only exists for the time the jobs run, which may only be milliseconds.